# preq_replace a url but last word is also replaced

Tags: php, regex

I am using a Twitter API plugin called `notwitterapi`.
I have a problem with replacing a link in a tweet. It replaces the link and puts an anchor around it but it also takes the last word of the tweet so it looks like this:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscinghttp://pic.twitter.com/

instead of:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing http://pic.twitter.com/

I have almost no experience with PHP.
This is the code that regexes the link from the text:

```
$find = $finder->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), 'js-tweet-text')]");
$data .= '"tweet":"'. preg_replace(
    "@((https?://)?([-\w]+\.[-\w\.]+)+\w(:\d+)?(/([-\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)*)@", 
    "<a href='$1' target='blank'>$1</a>",
    htmlspecialchars($find->item(0)->nodeValue, ENT_QUOTES)) . '"';
```

And this is the part that replaces it:

```
$data = str_replace("pic.twitter.com", "http://pic.twitter.com", $data);
```

And here is a link to the full code [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/h9D3zKKK).

I have tried changing the regex but since I don't know where the problem is I'm not sure that will work.

[image]

**EDIT**

> string(63) " Mediamonks tweet with link test6.pic.twitter.com/fuRbNYdCgs " string(63) " Mediamonks tweet with link test5.pic.twitter.com/aSZC3duVgY " string(63) " Mediamonks tweet with link test4.pic.twitter.com/zbieGQ8Lob " string(62) " Mediamonks tweet with link test3pic.twitter.com/3xlc1Duaqz " string(62) " Mediamonks tweet with link test2pic.twitter.com/SrM0kGnMFu " string(61) " Mediamonks tweet with link testpic.twitter.com/T7HMxZPXqp "

Comment: You can add an space before `<a href=`, like: `$data   .=  '"tweet":"' . preg_replace("@((https?://)?([-\w]+\.[-\w\.]+)+\w(:\d+)?(/([-\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)*)@", " <a href='$1' target='blank'>$1</a>", htmlspecialchars($find->item(0)->nodeValue, ENT_QUOTES)) . '"';`

Comment: @JoséM.Carnero That doesn't work sadly :(

Comment: You can try a working example in https://regex101.com/r/rV6kR1/1 . I don't test other logic than the regex logic, maybe the value passed to `preg_replace` is not the expected value?

Comment: @JoséM.Carnero not working in my case for some reason it places the last word in the anchor

Comment: Can you show what value has `$find->item(0)->nodeValue` just before used in `pref_replace`? I try the code in your question (with a fake "$find" value) and seems to work.

Comment: @JoséM.Carnero How can i check that? Thanks for the help ;)

Comment: You can show the value with `var_dump($find->item(0)->nodeValue)` or `print_r($find->item(0)->nodeValue)`. Edit your question adding the information.

Comment: @JoséM.Carnero Done!

Comment: All seems to work with that text, you can try it in https://regex101.com. Follow the value of `$data` after the `preg_replace` (you can print with `var_dump` anywhere), maybe is changed in other place. Sorry if I can't give you more help.